# How can I render bold text which is randomly set in a sentence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I would like to render bold string which on the random position in the sentence.

So far I was thinking about this approach

```
const wordToMatch = 'apples';
const sentence = 'I like apples and bananas';

sentence.split(' ').map(string=> {
  return string === wordToMatch ? <b>{string}</b> : {string}
}).join(' ');
```

I'm receiving an array of objects and one of them (the one I get match) looks like this.

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {children: undefined}
ref: null
type: "b"
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 0, key: null, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, stateNode: null, …}
_store: {validated: false}
```

Comment: Can't understand from the question the problem. Do you wan't  to know how can we render bold words in HTML? I am not able to understand the exact problem. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Yes exactly, as a final output I would like to render something like this: 'I like <b>apples<b> and bananas'.

Comment: The above approach will work fine... then what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work well without joining map result ,just add space after not matched word and React render will render maps elements (string or jsx object )

see below snippet :

```js
const wordToMatch = 'apples';
const sentence = 'I like apples and bananas';

let output = sentence.split(' ').map(string=> {
  return string === wordToMatch ? <b>{string} </b> : string+" "
});

ReactDOM.render(output,document.getElementById("txt"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="txt"></div>
```